# Event validation

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

We are considering implementing CQRS pattern at work and have a couple of questions about validation.

Let's say we have 3 aggregate roots:

- `User`
- `Business`
- `UserToBusinessRelationship`

When user signs up the events sent would be:

```
UserCreated
BusinessCreated
UserAddedToBusiness
```

Events need to be validated, for example to create a link between a user and a business both user and business should be created.

I see two approaches.

1. Upfront validation: construct read model on the fly using last processed snapshot plus unprocessed events and use it for validation.
2. Validation while processing: accept events/commands as-is and do the validation while processing events.

The first approach has immediate feedback but it requires creating a final read model just for validation. Second is simpler, but gives no feedback to consumer that something went wrong.

I was thinking about something like this: when you emit an event, you get back an id which you can later use to query the status of an event. If event processing was successful you'd get 'OK', otherwise you'd get an error telling what went wrong.

Is it a valid approach or an overkill? How would a consumer know that event has been processed and the data is ready to be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "event validation"? In CQRS only commands are validated; after they are accepted and event are generated, those events must be accepted, they are considered *very* valid, they represent facts that already happened.

Comment: Maybe answer to your question is here:  http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/22/4-secrets-inter-aggregate-communication-event-sourced-system/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question Leonti - You may find my blog post on validation in a CQRS system helpful. You can find the link to my post at the bottom of this answer.

Just notice from the title that the emphasis in CQRS is to validate commands and not events.

Why?

Because a command can come from user input and shouldn't, therefore, be trusted.
Events, on the other hand, are emitted from within the domain and can be trusted. There may be implementations of CQRS which involve events leaving the bounds of a system or receiving events which are not originated from within the system. In those edge cases, care should be applied.

Another potential red flag is the way you have described your aggregates. It would appear to me (and I don't know your domain so can't be 100% sure) that they are more akin to tables in a database rather than aggregates. It's important not to let the way your persistence mechanism dictate your models.

Getting back to your question more specifically.

Broadly speaking there are 2 types of validation. Superficial and deep. Superficial is stuff like missing fields, valid email addresses etc. Deep is when a domain concept is at play. e.g. the weight of the cargo is required and a superficial validation but whether or not the cargo is appropriate for the carrier may be a domain concept.

You may need to validate against the existence of things.e.g. Does a business or user exist. While this validation will more than likely require you to access the database, it is still superficial as it is unlikely to be an explicit domain concept.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

> Note: please read the comment about this link
> Blogpost URL: `https://danielwhittaker.me/2016/04/20/how-to-validate-commands-in-a-cqrs-application`

Comment: Just an FYI, I got a spam website the first time I clicked that link in the answer. The second time I did get the right website. Possibly the host is infected. I had to 'accept notifications' to continue from some sites called purplestock and mithrilminer. I will therefore disable clicking the link with a warning.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main aspects here:

1. In CQRS you have commands and queries. Where events are coming from? Assuming you also mean Event Sourcing, still, when using commands, you do some validation on the client, some in the command handler and some inside your domain model (aggregate invariants and constraints). This particular example looks like something that is validated on the client and inside the command handler.
2. Remember that since you have three distinct operations on three different aggregates, you need to have three transactions. This means, if one of those will not complete - you system will come to an invalid state. You either need to reconsider aggregate boundaries to have one aggregate root, or think about using other techniques like event-driven policies, sagas (process managers) or routing slips (sagas).

Definitely, `UserToBusinessRelationship` does sound more like a RDBMS many-to-many link table than an aggregate, but I don't know anything about your domain.